# Opening Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS Developer Edition - [yourmachinename]?

Tags: installation, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm attempting to run WAP Developer Edition for the first time. The instructions are to:

"On Windows, double-click the startup.bat file in the unzipped folder. The batch file starts the Node.js server in the Command Prompt window and Web AppBuilder in your default browser with http://[yourmachinename]:3344/webappbuilder. If the browser is closed, you can reopen Web AppBuilder in the same—or a different—browser as long as Node.js is running in the Command Prompt window."

The browser does not open automatically for me so I need to type in the URL.

How can I determine what [yourmachinename] is for my computer?

Comment: So you want to know how to look up your computer name with `hostname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `http://localhost:3344/webappbuilder/` or

**Windows**

find your computer name through the Control Panel:

1. Open the Control Panel.
2. Click System and Security > System.
3. On the View basic information about your computer page, see the Full computer name under the section Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings.

([more info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/do-you-need-help-locating-your-computer-name-00384381-8aa9-4398-b81b-475f09fed618))

**Mac**

find the computer name under System Preferences > Sharing

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Gavin. Do you know how I can go about this on a Mac? I am running Mac OS High Sierra, not Windows. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. The page you linked to showed me what I should be googling for. I was able to find the computer name under System Preferences > Sharing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @lisa.sedano ok great - I've updated the answer. Please "Accept" the answer if it works for you.